# frequency of odometry updates for navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working my way through the tutorial for the navigation stack. I have odometry msgs being published at about 12Hz (that's how fast they come in from the HW). The tutorial doesn't have any recommendation about frequency of odom updates, but I have found at least one thread here that mentions someone using 800Hz.  I could increase from 12 Hz, but could not get above 50Hz given the current HW I have.  Laser scan updates at ~3Hz.

This is for a tank-steer about 20cm across that should be able to move at maybe 30cm/sec.

What frequency have you guys been successful (or unsuccessful) with? Does 12 - 50Hz sound feasible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235050/frequency-of-odometry-updates-for-navigation-stack/) by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1850 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, if you get your odometry at 12Hz and your max speed is 0.3m/sec that means that if your robot is moving at max speed it will travel 0.025m (2.5cm) between odometry updates. If that is something you can live with, then it is OK.

I usually work with a robot that publishes odometry at ~20Hz with 0.5m/sec max speed without any major issue, although to avoid overshooting or oscillating around a goal point in autonomous navigation, the robot needs to drive slowly when close to the goal.

As a rule of thumb, the finest control you want the higher rate you need.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-05-23**:
That's the feedback I was hoping for. Thanks for your help.